# Start-Process arguments not working within Function

Tags: powershell

Ok, so I was looking for a quick way to run the current script in ISE that I'm working on in an external PS window - it's going to be used by the team so I wanted to work out formatting and that the menu options displayed correctly etc

This finds the current tab file script in ISE:

```
$ArgList = $psISE.CurrentFile.FullPath
```

This launches a new Powershell window and runs the script (file argument constructed in case script has a space in the path):

```
start-process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-file `"$($ArgList.path)`""
```

Running these two consecutively and interactively works fine

Problem being, if I run the two within a function like this:

```
Function ISERunInNewWindow {
$ArgList = $psISE.CurrentFile.FullPath
start-process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-file `"$($ArgList.path)`""
}
```

...it produces this error:

*Processing -File ' ' failed: The path is not of a legal form. Specify a valid path for the -File parameter.*

I know I must be missing something obvious, but it's eluding me as I don't use Powershell too often - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok - for anyone's info - it WAS something obvious as suspected.

Amending this:

```
start-process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-file `"$($ArgList.path)`""
```

To this:

```
start-process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-file `"$($ArgList)`""
```